# how to sum the visible fields of a column (not suppressed one) in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have Crystal Report whose column data is like following:

- 81306
- suppressed (real value was 81306)
- Total   81306 (Result Required)
- Total   162612 (Result coming which is not required)

[image]

Comment: share a screenshot of your report please, if you can!?

Comment: You could use running total field, where you should set evaluate condition to value change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to create a Formula field this way:

```
IF {rpt.Amount}= previous({rpt.Amount}) then 0 else {rpt.Amount}
[drag the field into the formula]
```

and then summarize this Formula field instead of the original field.

To summarize the formula field, the easiest way is
  1) mouse right button inside the report
  2) insert \ summary
  3) choose the formula field, SUM as summarize, the Group where yuou want to summarize into

Comment: Suppression rule is suppressed if duplicate value in a group. do not understand what the formula will be !

Comment: did you try using just the summary field without using any formula?

Comment: I am not using any formula, just only using sum function.

Comment: Summary field won't ever care if a value is duplicate.. it just sums all values! That's why you should evaluate per each line the value you want to consider (using a Formula), and then summarize it. I edited my answer to show how to create a formula.

Comment: After successfully showing the correct result by using Emanuele formula, The field is not going to summarize. The summary icon is closed for the formula field. Please Help

Comment: To summarize the formula field, the easiest way is 1)mouse right button inside the report 2) insert \ summary 3) choose the formula field, SUM as summarize, the Group where yuou want to summarize into